# Why do Ubuntu 20.04 get very slow in speed comparison to Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, 20.04, graphics

I have upgraded Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 via Graphical software upgrade option.I also replaced everything by new packages what was requiring during installation process.But then after was v4l2loopback installation issue due to subprocess although it is already resolved by internet help.But my Ubuntu get typically slow with comparison to previous ubuntu 18.04.Then I also have installed nvidia-driver-440 and also update,upgrade,clean,removing packages ,changing display into  Fractional Scaling ,Refresh Rate 48.02 Hz but there is no still improvement.htop menu is showing in the picture.
My system configaration is
CPU Intelcore i3 1.70 GHz,2cores 4 threads
Ram 8GB
Graphics mesa dri intel hd graphics 4400(HSW gt2)

I may going back into ubuntu 18.04 but before I write this in here to get usefull help to improve the speed.[image]Thankyou